# How to evaluate an expression in a for loop in C programming?

Tags: c, for-loop, cubic

I am trying to print cube of all the numbers from 1 to 20 (*n*<sup>3</sup>). I was wondering in my code if

```
printf("Enter an integer value\n");
```

is necessary. What's the purpose of that line? Can someone explain? Thanks. It's my first day learning C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter an integer value\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    for ( num=1; num<21; num++){
        printf("The cube of %d is %d\n", num, num*num*num);
    }
    getchar();
}
```

Comment: Did you google for `printf`? See [printf(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html)

Comment: And since you are starting to learn C: enable all warnings and debug info in your compiler (e.g. compile using `gcc -Wall -g` if using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...) and **learn** *now* **how to use the debugger** (e.g. `gdb`).

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch or just use Visual Studio and switch to Debug

Comment: I wish for the OP that he is learning on Linux.

Answer (score 3):

By using `printf()` you are printing msg "Enter an integer value" on the screen.
By using `scanf()` you are taking the value which you have typed on screen into `num` variable(i.e. initializing `num`).But in forloop you are reinitializing your `num` variable to "1" to "21".So `printf()` and `scanf()` are just waste of time , here .

if you want a specific numbers cube then just do as follows,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
void main() 
{
     int num;

     printf("Enter an integer value\n");
     scanf("%d", &num);

     printf("The cube of %d is %d\n", num, num*num*num);

     getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It is a meaningless

```
printf("Enter an integer value\n");
scanf("%d", &num);
```

it just display the message and read the value from keyboard, but in for loop 
when you assign 1 to the variable **num**  then previous value of **num** override.

Answer (score 0):

it doesn't serve for anything in your code.

You are getting the variable `num` but you are neglecting it very soon `for ( num=1 ...`

If you want it as a *useful* you can do something similar :

```
int num, i;
printf("Enter an integer value\n");
scanf("%d", &num);
for ( i=1; i<num; i++){   // print the cube of all numbers less than the entered value
    printf("The cube of %d is %d\n", i, i*i*i);
}
getchar();
```

Otherwise, you can just erase those two lines code:

```
printf("Enter an integer value\n");
scanf("%d", &num);
```

Answer (score 0):

the line printf("Enter an integer value\n");

display the words "Enter an integer value" to the user of the program,

in your code the next to lines have no meaning, here you ask the user to enter a integer, then save that number:

```
 printf("Enter an integer value\n");
 scanf("%d", &num);
```

because in the next line you set parameter num to be 1.

this next code scan the user input and then calculate the cube:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) 
{
    int num;
    printf("Enter an integer value\n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    printf("The cube of %d is %d\n", num, num*num*num);
}
```